# FTP client class is not connecting

Tags: java, ftp

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
FileInputStream fis = null;


try {
    client.connect("32.178.10.121");
    client.login("XXX", "XXX");

    //
    // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
    //
    String filename = "Touch.dat";
    fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

    //
    // Store file to server
    //
    client.storeFile(filename, fis);
    client.logout();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
        client.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have tried this but each time it gives time out of bound exception and by other means of i am successfully getting connected but nt from here what could be reason.

this is the stacktrace:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultSocketFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:162)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:250)
    at forTesting.FileUploadDemo.main(FileUploadDemo.java:15)
```

Comment: Can you share the exception stack trace? Also are you using Apache Commons FTPClient?

Comment: Do you think the exception is readable in the comment?? :P

Comment: pls see now i had added exception trace at question frame

Comment: Are you behind any proxy?

Comment: You can also have a look at [this](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) ..it works for me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First try to set the proxy details like below

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPHTTPClient(proxyHost, proxyPort, proxyUser, proxyPassword);
```

Then try to connect as you are doing and let me know if the error is gone.

If the error persists then check the firewall setting for the FTP server. Also try to connect from the System with some GUI tool like Filezilla to connect to the server.

Comment: Actually i need to get upload in any crossrefrence say XXXX in Ip and then a library in XXXX then to how get connect to this path

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question here? I din;t get it

Comment: need to upload a file in IP/Crossreference/library then how to get connect to library

Comment: are you still not getting wat i mean to say?

Comment: I was busy in something.sorry..Waht you are doing is fine to upload a file.But get the FTPClient as i have done here..

Comment: why sorry..its ok. infact i am if i disturb you. but i cant understand what you mean to say how could i get what i want if you understand well my requirement.

Comment: I was also getting the same exception as above stated in question, after changing the FTPClient object, I am getting some different exception stating : connection failure

Comment: please help me in this

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using PASV mode, if you're behind a firewall or proxy. Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol):

> In situations where the client is behind a firewall and unable to
>   accept incoming TCP connections, passive mode may be used. In this
>   mode, the client uses the control connection to send a PASV command to
>   the server and then receives a server IP address and server port
>   number from the server, which the client then uses to open a
>   data connection from an arbitrary client port to the server IP address
>   and server port number received.