# Upload a file by FTP at a specfic location

Tags: java, ftp

[FTP client class is not connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542670/ftp-client-class-is-not-connecting/15544823#15544823)

further to this link i just want to know to upload a file in specific directory location for example there is a cross reference in IP and then further a library in cross reference then how would i upload file in library or in precise how would i get connected to `ip/cross reference/library`  for location where i need to upload a file. here i want to mention that i successfully get connected to IP till now.

Comment: have you tried appending the path before the filename?

Comment: @Anubhab yes for example i have tried client.connect("32.56.112.52\\Crossrefrence\\Library"); bt it not works.

Comment: no..i am talking about `client.storeFile("/cross reference/library/myfile.txt",fis)` kind of thing

Comment: @Anubhab how can i use this client.storeFile("/cross reference/library/myfile.txt",fis)...I have a location at server IP/cross reference/library and at as child of library i want to upload a file say myfile.txt. I hope now you and understand it as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of FTPHTTPClient doesn't appear to take a path in the constructor, its just the hostname/ip.  Also, most FTP clients use / and not \ as the path separator.

The JavaDoc for [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) shows there is a method [changeWorkingDirectory(String pathname),](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#changeWorkingDirectory%28java.lang.String%29) which I am guessing is what you want to do.